# A Challenging One : How to convert a singly linked list into a staggered linked list using C language?

Tags: c

> **A Challenging One: How to convert a singly linked list into a staggered linked list using C language?**
> By Modifying the order of a linked list in the following pattern, adding the current node to the result list after every step:
>
> - Start at the head
> - Take two steps forward
> - Take one step back
> - Take three steps forward
> - Go to step 3 unless outside end of list
> - Add unvisited element at end of list to result, if any

**Example 1 : Odd no. of elements**

Input:

```
0->1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8->NULL
```

Output:

```
0->2->1->4->3->6->5->8->7->NULL
```

---

**Example 2: Even no. of elements**

Input:

```
0->1->2->3->4->5->6->7->NULL
```

Output:

```
0->2->1->4->3->6->5->7->NULL
```

---

For one or two elements, return as is.

**For 3 elements:**

Input:

```
0->1->2
```

Output:

```
0->2->1->NULL
```

---

Here's what I tried but not running successfully on all input cases:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Node {
    const int val;
    struct Node *next;
};

void stagger(struct Node *head) {
    struct Node *curr, *slow, *fast='\0';
    curr = head;

    if (curr == '\0') {
        printf("NULL");
        return;
    }

    if (curr->next == '\0' || curr->next->next == '\0') {
        while (curr) {
            printf("%d->",curr->val);
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    } else {
        while (fast) {
            printf("%d->",curr->val); //0-1
            fast = slow->next->next;
            slow = curr->next;
            printf("%d->",fast->val); //2-1
            printf("%d->",slow->val); //1-1
            curr = slow->next->next;
            printf("%d->",curr->val);
        }
    }

    printf("NULL");
}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Please, as a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your question does not meet quality requirements yet. For example, "not running successfully" is not a problem description and it lacks a [mcve].

Comment: Aside: The use of the [character constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/character_constant) `'\0'` in place of `NULL` is strange at best. Use `NULL` explicitly, or logical NOT to infer the same result (`foo == NULL` is the same as `!foo`).

Comment: @Abdul Malik Initially the pointer fast is initialized as a null pointer *fast='\0';. So the while loop while (fast) { will not be executed.

Comment: @vlad-from-moscow   I have removed that initialization, but I think i'm not getting it right in the while loop...

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt , sorry but I hope the explanation conveys the idea. I will improve next time. thanks

Comment: @Abdul Malik In any case your approach is invalid because you need to reorganize the list instead of just printing its values .

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you described can be thought of as swapping every two consecutive nodes after the zeroth.

This task can be made very simple:

```
// n0 must not be NULL
void stagger(struct Node *n0) {
  struct Node *n1 = n0->next;
  if (!n1) return;
  struct Node *n2 = n1->next;
  if (n2) {
    /*
      at this time, n0->n1->n2->n3...
      we want n0->n2->n1->n3...
      n0, n1, and n2 are all valid pointers to Nodes. n3 may be NULL
    */
    struct Node *n3 = n2->next;
    n0->next = n2;
    n1->next = n3;
    n2->next = n1;
    // n1 will be n0 in the next call to stagger, with n1->n3... now n0->n1...
    stagger(n1);
  }
}
```

If recursion is not your thing, the same can be achieved with a while-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [nathaniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18349142/nathaniel)

That was of much help in rearranging the pointers, and here the final version I reached (just made n0 to head and added printing) that works as expected in the challenge

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Node {
    int val;
    struct Node *next;
};
 void stagger(struct Node *head) {

  if(!head) // handling empty list
  {
    printf("NULL");
    return;
  }
   struct Node *n1 = head->next;

  if(!head->next || !head->next->next ) // handling 1 or 2 elements
  {
    while(head)
    {
      printf("%d->",head->val);
      head = head->next;
    }
    printf("NULL");
    return;
  }
   
  struct Node *n2 = n1->next;
  if(n2)
  {
    printf("%d->",head->val);
    printf("%d->",n2->val);
    struct Node *n3 = n2->next;
    head->next = n2;
    n1->next = n3;
    n2->next = n1;
    stagger(n1);

  }
}
```

I hope this might help, Actually This code modifies the original list and Here I ask for one more contribution to save the newly arranged elements into a new list without modifying the old one, It's very simple :)